# Format an entire text with pattern.en?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I need to analyse some texts for a machine learning purpose. A data scientist I know advised me to use [pattern.en](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-en) for my project.

I will give my program a keyword (**Example** : pizza), and it has to sort some "trends" from several texts I give him. (**Example** : I give him texts which talk about nutella on pizzas, so the program would identify that nutella is a growing trend.)

So for the start, I have to "clean" the text. I know that *pattern.en* can identify words as a noun, verb, adverb etc., I want to remove all determiners, articles and other "meaningless" words for my analyses, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to `parse()` so I can get :

```
s = "Hello, how is it going ? I am tired actually, did not sleep enough... That is bad for work, definitely"
parsedS = parse(s)
print(parsedS)
```

That outputs :

```
Hello/UH/hello ,/,/, how/WRB/how is/VBZ/be it/PRP/it going/VBG/go ?/./?
I/PRP/i am/VBP/be tired/VBN/tire actually/RB/actually ,/,/, did/VBD/do not/RB/not sleep/VB/sleep enough/RB/enough .../:/...
That/DT/that is/VBZ/be bad/JJ/bad for/IN/for work/NN/work ,/,/, definitely/RB/definitely
```

So I'd like to remove words with tags "UH", ",", "PRP" etc. but I don't know how to do it, and without messing with the sentences (For analyzing purposes, I will ignore sentences without the word "pizza" in my **Example**)

I don't know if I am very clear in my explanations, feel free to ask me if you didn't understand something.

**EDIT - UPDATE :** After *canyon289*'s answer, I would like to do it sentence by sentence, not for the entire text. I tried :

```
for sentence in Text(s):
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    print("SENTENCE :")
    for word in sentence:
        if not any(tag in word for tag in dont_want):
            print(word)
```

But I have the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'Sentence' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```
s = "Hello, how is it going ? I am tired actually, did not sleep   enough... That is bad for work, definitely"
s = parse(s)

#Create a list of all the tags you don't want
dont_want = ["UH", "PRP"]

sentence = parse(s).split(" ")

#Go through all the words and look for any occurence of the tag you don't want
#This is done through a nested list comprehension
[word for word in sentence if not any(tag in word for tag in dont_want)]
```

> [u',/,/O/O', u'how/WRB/O/O', u'is/VBZ/B-VP/O', u'going/VBG/B-VP/O',
>   u'am/VBP/B-VP/O', u'tired/VBN/I-VP/O', u'actually/RB/B-ADVP/O',
>   u',/,/O/O', u'did/VBD/B-VP/O', u'not/RB/I-VP/O', u'sleep/VB/I-VP/O',
>   u'enough/RB/B-ADVP/O', u'.../:/O/O\nThat/DT/O/O', u'is/VBZ/B-VP/O',
>   u'bad/JJ/B-ADJP/O', u'for/IN/B-PP/B-PNP', u'work/NN/B-NP/I-PNP',
>   u',/,/O/O', u'definitely/RB/B-ADVP/O']

Comment: Check the object type of sentence. My guess is that it's not a string

Comment: Definitely. By searching in the `tree.py` file in the lib, I've found the "Sentence.string" attribute, which returns the string corresponding to the sentence. :) There is no "Javadoc-like" for those kind of projects ? That could be very helpful ><